# John Hsu: File missing from gazebo_plugins package libgazebo_ros_time.cpp libgazebo_ros_time.so Meka A2

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04
Fuerte

John, or anyone else:

It looks like the source to build libgazebo_ros_time.so has been removed from gazebo_plugins?

The page for the package
http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins
still mentions the GazeboRosTime plugin.

So, has this plugin been removed due to changes in Gazebo?

Thanks,
David.

.

More info:

I'm trying to launch the Meka A2 Virtual Robot, as per this page:
http://mekabot.com/wiki/doku.php?id=user_guides:software:ros_tutorials

While Gazebo is trying to launch, I get an error:
Error [Plugin.hh:100] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_time.so: libgazebo_ros_time.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Searching Google reveals 2 threads suggesting that the gazebo_plugins package did not compile correctly.

I double-checked that it did compile correctly, then I checked the SVN for gazebo_plugins and noticed that the file libgazebo_ros_time.cpp is missing.

I decided to check when the file was removed from the SVN...

Current revision is 39596

In a new directory:
% svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins@38276

revision 38276 20 Oct 2011 by hsu
was the last revision I could find the source for the time plugin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36416/john-hsu:-file-missing-from-gazebo_plugins-package-libgazebo_ros_time.cpp-libgazebo_ros_time.so-meka-a2/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the tutorial in http://mekabot.com/wiki/doku.php?id=user_guides:software:ros_tutorials, which works with Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) with karma: 230 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0